# Closing equation in a set of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

What does a closing equation mean in a set of equations?  I tried to solve a couple of equations governing the motion of ions in a plasma. The poisson's equation serves as the closing equation. I didn't understand why is it called a closing equation.

Comment: Is it possible that the term is a *physics*?

Comment: I dont know . Is it not in mathematics ?@AirMike

Comment: I heard of *closed-form expressions*. I don’t know if that’s what you are looking for. Although, if it is some *physics* term, you can try the page in StackExchange dedicated to physics

Comment: I know about closed form solutions . But this is not it .

Comment: You say that the Poisson’s equation serves as the closing equation. Does it have to do with frontier conditions?

Comment: Now , what are the frontier conditions ?